# MongoDb java driver has not suitable methods for all mongodb queries

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to translate dynamic mongodb queries into java driver methods
but while following find queries are the valid in mongodb and return results, there are no suitable overloads of find method in java driver

```
db.users.find({name:"sue"},{_id:0},{},{},{},{},{})

db.users.find({name:"sue"},1,1)
```

Could someone help me by telling how can I execute all mongodb queries using java driver or should I use any other approach and is this right way to execute dynamic mongodb queries?

Comment: Where (and in which language) did you find the find() calls you posted? In mongo shell find() takes one or two parameters: the query and eventually a projection. These map to MongoCollection.find(Bson) and MongoCollection.find(Bson).projection(Bson) respectively. All other forms need further explanation.

Comment: I mean if I type this on mongo shell

db.users.find({name:"sue"},{_id:0},{},{},{},{},{})

it runs without error and returns the result
if I've to call the MongoCollection.find() with same parameters like


mongocollection.find(dbObject1,dbObject2,dbObject3,...)


how can I do that

Comment: This is probably because mongo shell ignores extra parameters, but what are you trying to achieve from a logical point of view?

Comment: execute dynamic mongo queries which are syntactically correct

Comment: You seem to misunderstand: there is *no differece* between db.users.find({name:"sue"},{_id:0},{},{},{},{},{}) and db.users.find({name:"sue"},{_id:0}). These additional parameters do not have any meaning. If the user enters a correct dynamic query, put it in the first parameter. If you want to do this in Java, create a Bson from the input and use MongoCollection.find()